# Catch block: can not read property 'catch' of undefined

Tags: error-handling, react-native, catch-block

I have problem with catch block which is not working and throwing an error.

This error came when i added that `NetInfo` if-else block before adding that block it worked but after adding it showing that error.
Here is my code in login.js

```
componentDidMount() {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((isConnected) => {
if ( isConnected )
{
  return fetch('http://10.42.0.1:8000/stocks/',
{
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `JWT ${"eyJhbGciOiJIUz1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNhbSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjYxLCJlbWFpbCI6IiIsImV4cCI6MTUwNDAzNDUzOX0.d3tbOUS_0L9RzkWA30DT8mv7v7j0XuxnRuI_luhuNzI"}`
  }
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    if (!responseJson.post){
    navigate("Login");
  }else
  {
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.setState({
    isLoading: false,
    sa: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.post),
  });
  }
})
}else
{
  navigate("Login");
  Alert.alert(
    'Check Internet connection',
    )
}
 }).catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
   })
}
```

[image]

where i am wrong? please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your .done to a .then.

I'd also suggest extracting some of that logic into separate functions to make it easier on yourself to read..Lots of braces and parens everywhere!

Comment: yes... thanks a lot it worked, But why is such what is reason behind it can you please explain?

Comment: @mayureshpatil .done is meant to be the last element in your chain, a terminating statement if you will.  Here's some good info about it.  http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html#sec_additional-promise-methods